# VMware import to Amazon EC 2

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I´m having a VMware image with Windows Server 2012 installed which I´m trying to import and convert to Amazon EC2.
I´m doing it from command line, and import process to Amazon S3 is successfully, but the conversion into an EC2 instance is failing. The error message I get is unsupported Windows version (Windows Server 2012 Server Standard), which is pretty strange because that OS version seems to be supported in Amazon EC2.

Someone who has experience about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can run an Amazon provided Windows 2012 image. It is not supported by the import tools.

> You can import VMware ESX and VMware Workstation VMDK images, Citrix
>   Xen VHD images and Microsoft Hyper-V VHD images for Windows Server
>   2003, Windows Server 2003 R2, Windows Server 2008 and Windows Server
>   2008 R2. You can export previously imported EC2 instances to VMware
>   ESX VMDK, VMware ESX OVA, Microsoft Hyper-V VHD or Citrix Xen VHD file
>   formats. We plan to support import for additional operating systems,
>   versions and virtualization infrastructure products in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Server 2012 is not supported by Amazon VM import.

Still if you are not tied to AWS by an already created infrastructure, you could try other clouds like ElasticHost, CloudSigma or Windows Azure.